# low level svn errors: coming from my machine or from the server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm getting intermittent errors like this when doing `svn update` from the command line.

```
svn: E200030: sqlite[S10]: disk I/O error

svn: E200033: Another process is blocking the working copy database, or the
underlying filesystem does not support file locking; if the working copy is 
on a network filesystem, make sure file locking has been enabled on the file 
server

svn: E200033: sqlite[S5]: database is locked, executing statement 'PRAGMA 
synchronous=OFF;PRAGMA recursive_triggers=ON;PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;PRAGMA 
locking_mode = NORMAL;'
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out if they are coming from my local machine or from the svn server.  I have found some indications online that these types of messages may be local and caused by TortoiseSVN.

Other devs on my team don't seem to get these errors. Could it be that it's not supported to use svn from the command line while TortoiseSVN is running? (I don't think other devs on my team do that, only me... my main use of the command line is to run a batch file that updates all of my svn working folders so I don't have to update them one by one)

Comment: Usually, this kind of problem is solved using right click > TortoiseSVN > **Clean up...**

Comment: TortoiseSVN > Clean up... solved my problem. After that I could use svn commands from terminal. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting your question. It helped me solve a similar problem in which I had Eclipse open with Subversive in the background.

Answer (score 7):

Those are coming from your machine.  SVN [since version 1.7 has used a SQLite database](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng) for the working copy pristines and metadata (the `.svn` folder in your working copy).  The server uses just the bare file system.

I've never seen these, but I could see how running a TortoiseSVN operation at the same time as a command line SVN command might cause this.  They'd both attempt to access the `.svn` folder and the SQLite database inside it.

Comment: I am not running a TortoiseSVN operation at the same time as a command line command... it's just that the TortoiseSVN process is *running* at the same time as my command line.

Comment: I see.  Well, I don't have a lot of guesses as to what would be causing it outside of what the error message already said.  Do you have a virus scanner running by chance?  It grabbing a lock on the database is at least consistent with you saying it happens intermittently...

Comment: Well, I'm thinking maybe Tortoise does some things in the background without you interacting with it.  For instance there is something called Tortoise Cache.

Comment: It does, but it generally wouldn't be writing to the database (which should be the only thing that locks that file).  Stefan roams the site from time to time, he may be able to offer more input.